# How to name a class that performs both creation and update of objects

Tags: java, c#, oop

The class has the following methods:

CreateEmployee

UpdateEmployee

I was going to be it EmplyeeCrud, but as the class doesn't perform deletions I don't think this is an appropriate name. Also the term "crud" doesn't sound nice in the context of a class name. I was also thinking of naming it EmployeeFactory, but my understanding is that factories are for creation rather than updates. I also thought about naming it EmployeeManager but this suggests that it is a God-like class which it isn't.

I'd appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit - "Name that thing" questions are frequently closed as "Primarily Opinion Based" on Progs.  I don't think this question would fare well there.

Comment: @GlenH7: It fares even worse here, for much the same reason. This is completely opinion-based and should be closed.

Comment: You should really format your question.

Comment: If you find it hard to think of a name for a class, it's probably doing too much. It also sounds like a bad design here, why have one class that is just data and then another class (or clases) that manipulate it. The most logical thing to do is have constructors to create and methods to update... ie OOP

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit as Glen said, this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat: Yes, Glen already covered that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Two common names for objects that perform CRUD functions are "Registry" and "Repository", so I would pick one of these names. For example, `EmployeeRegistry` sounds reasonably self-descriptive:

```
public interface EmployeeRegistry {
    Employee createEmployee(/* some args */);
    void updateEmployee(Employee e, /* more args */);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but please with method names that start with a lowercase character. (-:

Comment: @AdriaanKoster one of the tags is C#; Microsoft uses Pascal case convention for method names. ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw(v=vs.71).aspx )

Comment: Oops, missed that tag. But why both Java and C# I wonder...

Answer (score 1):

#### Do one thing at a time.

Objects should handle their own updates by convention of encapsulation. Whatever handles the data should simply parametrize dependencies.

If you so desire, create a pool/heap/container class to ensure that you have track of all of the `Employee` objects in your program. Then, have the container class decoupled from the actual objects so that you can just switch out either the container or the data and still have it work.

Analogy: If you are managing kids, don't try to micromanage or "touch" them all by yourself. Get somebody to take account of them. Then, you being the main() master programmer, just tell each kid what they need to do. No need to get physical with them--just organize everything so that one person keeps track, the other gives instructions, and the kids have the responsibility of changing their own activities.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should be using two classes and an interface described below:

Interface: Have an interface that describes method to do common tasks for any collection of objects such as rename, delete, update etc.

Class `Employee` that implements the Interface. And in the constructor you "create and setup the employee" with possibly multiple constructors.

And a container class that can call the Interface methods implemented in the `Employee` class. The container class itself could a list, vector or whatever you deem best.

Answer (score 0):

The best name for this class would be 'Employee' since it is operating solely on employees.

If the methods are accessing a data store then this might not be practical in the standard application layering / anemic object model approach we are used to. In that case you could call this class EmployeDao or EmployeeRepository for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class `EmployeeBuilder` and do the updating within a public method of the class `Employee`. `EmployeeBuilder` could hold data that is shared among certain Employees. The method `EmployeeBuilder#build()` would get all the information that is not shared among those employees as parameters and would call the constructor of `Employee`.

`EmployeeFactory` on the other hand should be a class that creates a concrete `EmployeeBuilder` based on some common data for example in which city they work.